# What it means for a differential form to be on a manifold and how to "find" it

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

In most of the cases I have studied, I haven't seen what it means for a form "to be" on the manifold. We usually let $M$ to be a manifold, and we let $\omega\in \bigwedge ^kT^*_pM$ in the exterior algebra of the dual tangent space, we then say $\omega$ is of the form $\sum_{I}f_Idx^I$ (I is a multiindex) and we don't give too much meaning. But all  this is abstract and much general.

How we can make sense of a form been on a manifold. Apart from the obvious, to say that $\omega$ "takes values" from the tangent space of the manifold.

Can we say anything about the coefficients (functions) of the form ?

I have been trying to answer this by looking the example of the sphere $S^2$, trying to deduce some information about the functions of the form by looking some evaluations of vector fields on the sphere.

So I think a nice answer to this question would be, to give an example of a $2$-form on the sphere.

Any example of your choice that answers this will do. But I always take the sphere as a "natural choice".

Comment: It depends on your definition of a manifold.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I mean the classic differential manifold, a topological space with smooth atlas.

Comment: Then the sentence "For example we say that a vector field is on a manifold if the inner product with respect to the metric is zero, i.e if it's tangent" is wrong. My suggestion is to stick to the textbook definition of differential forms. This should take care of your terminological confusion.

Comment: @MoisheKohan okay, then replace that statement with a vector field is on the manifold if it's a section of the tangent bundle, or ignore it.

Comment: Good, a differential k-form on $M$ is a section of the k-th exterior power of the cotangent bundle of $M$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan hm I see this indeed answers my question thank you, but can we have anything more "closed" in some specific cases ? Like for example, can we say anything about the coefficients as I mentioned.

Comment: I did not understand your question and I do not understand what you mean by "closed": there is a standard notion of a closed form but it seems that you mean something else. I suggest you revise your question for clarity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I mean "close" condition for it to be a section, do we have any restriction on the coefficients ? (I don't mean closed form)

Comment: Example of a 2-form on the sphere: Let $S$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ and let $\omega$ be a function which takes as input a point $p \in S$ and returns as output the function $\omega(p)$ defined as follows: if $v$ and $w$ are tangent vectors to $S$ at $p$ then $\omega(p)(v, w) = (v \times w) \cdot n$, where $n$ is the outward pointing unit normal vector to $S$ at $p$. Then $\omega$ is a 2-form on $S$.

Comment: littleO has given my favorite 2-form on the sphere, the standard generator of its top cohomology.  for its coordinate expression, and geometric meaning,  see Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds, p. 131., or Loomis-Sternberg, Advanced Calculus, p. 474-5.  This form can be used to show every smooth vector field on the sphere has a zero.

Answer (score 2):

A quote from Lee's Smooth Manifolds second edition page 360.

In any smooth chart, a k-form can be written locally as

$$\omega = \sum_I\omega_I dx^{i_1}\land \dots \land dx^{i_k}$$

where the coefficients $\omega_I$ are continuous functions defined on the coordinate domain. Proposition $10.22$ shows that $\omega$ is smooth on $U$ if and only if the coordinate functions $\omega_I$ are smooth.

So the answer to your question is that the coordinate functions must be continuous to be a k-form, and smooth to be a smooth k-form.

Here is an example in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

- A 0-form is a continuous real valued function.
- A 1-form is a co-vector field.
- Some examples of 2-forms are $$\omega = (\sin xy)dy\land dx$$ which is smooth because $\sin xy$ is smooth and $$\eta = dx\land dy + dx \land dz + dy \land dz$$
- Every 3-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a **continuous
  real-valued function times** $dx\land dy\land dz$

In conclusion the thing that we can say about the coefficients is that they are (smooth) continuous real valued functions of the coordinate domain to be a (smooth) k-form.

Comment: I upvote your answer, but the reason I don't accept as an answer is because I think one may dive deeper.  @MoisheKohan comment raises some interesting questions in MO. Are the sections global? If so, often enough such sections can be only trivial or non-existing, what that tells us ?